Travel to UK via Yerevan/Athens
My wife is a Russian citizen with UK visa. Does she need a Greek transit visa when flying Yerevan-Athens-London?

Would both flights be on the same ticket?

Yes,they would be on same ticket as aim to fly Yerevan-Athens-London

No; Russia is not amongst the countries for which that Greece requires an airport transit visa - see https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy/applying-schengen-visa_en

To prevent link rot, please quote the relevant parts of the link into your answer.

That’s of course only if the two flights are on the same ticket. If the flights are on separate tickets (self-transfer) then a full visa will be required.
